New Eaton AFCI/GFCI 40A 220V GFCI breaker signals (4 blinks) ground fault
I have installed a new Eaton BR240 (40A) GFCI Breaker. It is staying on for a while but can trip after several minutes or stay on for hours. The while indicator lights flash (4 times) which according to the Eaton website indicates a "High Level ground fault".
https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/products/electrical-circuit-protection/circuit-breakers/br-two-pole-ground-circuit-breaker.html
Pretty sure the GFCI is grounded correctly. Can anyone offer any suggestion as to how I can fix this issue?

There are several knowledgeable electricians around, but none of them are also mind-readers. Please add (at a minimum!) a photo of your main panel and the panel where this problematic breaker is installed, if it's different.

Can't even begin to answer this question without knowing what's connected to the breaker.

40 amp breakers are common for stoves/ranges.  If a stove, do you know if it wired up as nema 10 or nema 14 or nema 6 type circuit?  It should be a circuit(wires) problem or the appliance problem.  NEMA 10 might add to it.  NEMA 10 has been ban since 96, but allowed to be kept in place/grandfathered).

A GFCI breaker is not grounded at all. There is no way for a GFCI breaker to access ground. However, that is fine, since GFCIs don't use ground in any way. They are looking for differential current on the wires (i.e. current unaccounted for, that went out and did not return via this path).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILBjnZq0n8s

What circuit/appliance is the breaker powering?

GFCI breaker measures current it passes to the load via hot wire and current it receives back through neutral.
If there is a difference over threshold in either direction like 5mA (check breaker specs) — it will trip because current found a path that is considered a Ground Fault (or a leak to ground).
An example could be human accidentally holding hot contact of an outlet or appliance and touching some electrical path to the ground like a copper water line which is deadly. GFCI will see that less current comes back to its neutral than it sends to its load and it will trip, saving people and equipment.
Unless the breaker is defective or the wiring in the main panel is wrong then one common reason for unexplained GFCI tripping could be improperly connected neutrals in one (or few!) of the junction boxes down the line.
Ie load that is supposed to run to a separate breaker uses neutral from your GFCI breaker (or vice-versa) to return its current because it sees it as a less resistant path, GFCI breaker sees difference over threshold and trips.
A solution could be like so:

Find and isolate breakers that trip the GFCI breaker when their loads are running together. This might include turning all breakers off while GFCI breaker is on and has a load running and then turning one other breaker with some running load on it like a bulb or even better a variable load, once you find other breaker(s) that trip your GFCI breaker — mark them and turn entire panel off because you'll need to go trace it now and wires need to be safe to work with, always double check wires with voltmeter and wear PPE.
Then the hard part — tracing neutral wires. In the junction points (outlets, light switches, in the attic) there are likely some neutrals that were joined together from separate breakers thus allowing current to flow back to a breaker it's not supposed to go to. Tracing can be done with a long extension cord between main panel and junction box and continuity check on the multimeter.
Once you find which separated neutral wire belongs to which breaker — mark them and make sure you re-join them correctly so that neutrals are not shared between breakers anymore but they still make a full run between loads back to its breaker.

Please note that separating neutrals is not just to keep GFCI from tripping, it is a problem on its own that can lead to neutral overload and fire danger — when another load returns its current to improper neutral together with its own neutral current. It can also lead to weird voltages between circuits sitting on different 120V phases coming into the house.
That's one potential answer, could be something else but I don't know what.
This is not a professional advice, always follow safety rules and regulations in your area, call a licensed electrician.
